# Sum of random variables $\mathbf{x}\sim \text{Uniform}(\mathbb{S}^{n−1})$ converges to Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, concentration-of-measure, gaussian

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\sim \text{Uniform}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ and $z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. How to prove for any $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$
$$\Big|\mathbb{P}\Big\{\sum_i x_i \in A \Big\} - \mathbb{P}\Big\{z \in A \Big\}\Big| \to 0$$
?

Intuitively, I think the statement is true. Since for $n\to\infty$, $\mathbf{x}$ approximates $\mathbf{y}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}_n)$ as the mess of high-dimensional Gaussian distribution concentrates around the unit sphere scaled by $\sqrt{n}$.
And $\sum_i y_i$ is equivalent to $z$.

But can anyone give me a rigorous proof?

Comment: Take a smooth indicator function of A. This has some controllable lipschitz constant. Then the difference in probability is the difference in expectation of f(sum xi) and f(z). But f(sum xi) - f(z) <= C|sum xi-z| but the latter goes to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! What is smooth indicator? I understand probability is the integral of indicator function. But how can the smooth indicator be applied here? Any reference?

Comment: Its just a function thats 1 on A and 0 everywhere else. But you also want it to be continuous so it just looks like some hills

Comment: Is probability the integral of the *smooth* indicator function? Can you give some reference on the *smooth* indicator function?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BumpFunction.html